# Copy a Nokogiri node to a custom subclass

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML document that I'm parsing using ::parse, and there are few descendant elements inside the root node of the document that I would like to create copies of, but as a custom subclass of Nokogiri::XML::Element.

It seems like

```
MyElement.new('myElement', existingElement)
```

should do it, but the new object ends up being empty, except for the name. I'm hoping there's a better way of doing it than just iterating over all the attributes, and manually assigning the children, namespace, etc to the new object.

Is there something like a class method for #dup that takes an existing element? Or some other way of handling this?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the code you're writing? Adjusting your code is much easier than starting from scratch.

Comment: What would a custom subclass provide that the existing classes do not?

Comment: Nodes have a #dup method, which defaults to a deep copy.

Comment: Essentially I'm parsing a GPX (gps data) file. Rather than iterating over each node and loading the data into a brand new class, I was just going to add some new methods to Element. eg #distance_from(someOtherGpsWaypoint). I would just add the methods to XML::Element itself, but everything in the document ends up being an Element, and I don't want 'routes' and 'track segments' to have #distance_from, just 'waypoints'. So ideally, eg, if I parse out a 'track segment' w/150 'waypoints', I just copy each to a Waypoint (subclass of Element).